# Docker question: Does Docker link FROM images at runtime or during build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Does Docker link images at build time or execution time? I am presenting a very simple case here to demonstrate my dilemma but I am presently rebuilding a chain of Docker files every time I change the base docker image and Im not sure if I even need to.

I have two docker files:

my base-docker-file contains

```
# this is not based on another image

RUN build commands here
```

which I build with

```
docker build --no-cache -t base-image -f base-docker-file.
```

and my from-docker-file here:

```
# this is based on the base-image
FROM base-image

RUN build commands here
```

which I build with

```
docker build --no-cache -t from-image -f from-docker-file.
```

Based on this simple setup, do I need to rebuild my from-image whenever I make a change to my base-image or does image linking occur at run time?

Comment: `do I need to rebuild my from-image whenever I make a change to my base-image or does image` → yes. Old `from-image` using old layer of `base-image`. Even if you delete `base-image` all layers used by `from-image` will be saved as parts of `from-image`

Answer (score 0):

you will have to build each time if you make a change to the base-image. You could add these individual commands in a script to be executed together rather than running them separate everytime

Comment: So no dynamic linking from docker at runtime? That seems like a massive waste and duplication of memory. I wonder why it doesnt a single common image at runtime. That sounds like it  would be a big improvement in memory consumption.  Open to opinions...

Comment: Locally all of the built images will share the disk space (not memory) of the base image; as you say, they're linked to the base image layers and don't include copies.  At runtime, every container based on some image shares the disk space (not memory) of its (immutable) image and its base image(s), until it changes a file.

Answer (score -2):

## 1. Multi-stage build

Multi-stage build allows you to isolate images in one Dockerfile. [1](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Example:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM alpine:latest AS builder
RUN apk --no-cache add build-base

FROM builder
COPY source1.cpp source.cpp
RUN g++ -o /binary source.cpp
```

## 2. Turn off no-cache when building the base-image.

Simple. If there are no changes in the base image, it will not rebuild due to cache.

Comment: Thank you. My question is more basic than that:  I am asking how does docker link images in a simple scenario like this. i.e. Do I need to rebuild the derived images every time i rebuild the base.